# Refresh parent page grid on close popup in angular

Tags: angular, angular15

I have hard time to refresh parent page on close popup. As a workaround I am doing `window.location.reload()`  But I don't want to hard refresh the page. Just want to call ngOninit of parent page where I am binding the data to dx-datagrid. This popup is just adding a row in the grid so on close popup I want to refresh the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to call a function in `ngOninit` instead of calling `ngOninit` from somewhere and call that function whenever the `modal-popup` is closed.

If the `modal-popup` is a child of your parent component, you can use an `eventEmitter` to send the event to parent whenever the `modal-popup` is closed and perform necessary actions in the parent.

If such is not the case, you can use a `BehaviorSubject` in a service, and change the `BehaviorSubject's` value when the `modal-popup` is closed. Because of it's reactive nature, same will be updated on parent as well and the necessary action can be performed accordingly (In the `subscribe()` of the `BehaviorSubject`).